# convert woocommerce theme to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes, woocommerce-rest-api

how do I convert my woo commerce site into a dynamic WordPress site? I already integrated the the woo commerce theme into my WordPress but how do i customize the theme to work correctly in WordPress using php

Comment: You can edit your theme by creating a Child Theme. For more info check this - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Comment: this question is likely to attract down votes as to general and possibly of-topic for SO, suggest post these types of questions here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecommerce